# Можно ли использовать JS-файл как БД?

Tags: javascript, php, html, база-данных

Как вы на это смотрите?

Использовать JS-файл для хранения в нём набора переменных, в которых хранятся контенты для разных страниц. Объём JS-файла может быть 10-20 мб. При загрузке страницы из этого подключаемого файла выбирается соответствующая переменная и её содержмое вставляется через innerHTML на страницу.

Кажется, что при загрузке страницы этот объёмный файл не будет загружаться полностью, а будет только нужная его часть. Я уже реализовал поиск по сайту, основанный на этом принципе: в отдельный JS-файл кладётся массив с html-содержимым всех страниц (его вес получился 14 мб) и по нему происходит поиск. Страница и сами результаты загружаются мгновенно. **На загрузку страницы требуется длительное время, только если открыт DevTools, где визуализируется загрузка всего JS-файла.**

Ну и таким образом можно было бы извлекать нужные фрагменты из этой БД и для редактирования в том же TinyMCE, с последующим сохранением обратно в БД. Только через JS.

Comment: JS файл будет скачен полностью клиентом и загружен браузером. Использоваться будет то, к чему обращаетесь. В целом конечно можно так сделать, однако динамику лучше положить на сервер и запрашивать по необходимости

Comment: Так можно было и с localStorage побаловаться) Зачем складывать ВЕСЬ HTML, когда можно было хранить только данные в json?